# wpf style on devexpress buttonedit

Tags: wpf, devexpress

```
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
.
.
<Style x:Key="ButtonEditInSearchCriteriaStyle" TargetType="dxe:ButtonEdit">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="NullValueButtonPlacement" Value="EditBox"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDefaultButton" Value="False"/>
</Style>
 .
 .
<dxe:ButtonEdit Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.Column="3" 
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonEditInSearchCriteriaStyle}"/>
```

I get a error on the Style="{StaticResource ButtonEditInSearchCriteriaStyle}"

Error message: 
'ButtonEdit' Targettype does not match type of element 'ButtonEdit'

Answer (score 1):

Are you using two different devExpress versions in your solution?
If yes, this is known bug which hasn't been resolved. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T373315/wpf-theme-issue-targettype-does-not-match-type-of-element

Comment: Yes I had, I removed one and now it works, thanks =)